# how to make a sql loop?

Tags: sql, recursive-query

here is the simplified table

```
filesystem (id, name, parentId);
```

and some entries

```
(1, 'root', NULL)
(2, 'folder', 1)
(3, 'subfolder', 2)
(4, 'subsubfolder', 3)
```

is there a way using native SQL to print the absolute path of one entry ?

for instance, the last entry would print 'root/folder/subfolder/subsubfolder'. the entry 2 would print 'root/folder' and so on.

Comment: Are you comfortable in changing your database structure?

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/blog/2015-02/modern-sql

Comment: What's wrong with his data structure? It seems fine

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your DBMS, the following is standard (ANSI) SQL:

```
with recursive folder_tree as (
   select id, name, parentid, name as fullpath
   from filesystem
   where parentid is null
   union all 
   select c.id, c.name, c.parentid, p.fullpath||'/'||c.name 
   from filesystem c
      join folder_tree p on c.parentid = p.id
)
select *
from folder_tree
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91332/7

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I come back to you because I noticed your solution didn't help me, it doesn't show the absolute paths. Just the parent's folder for each folder instead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it did not, i replaced p.fullpath||'/'||c.name in the query and now it does.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name here is what I tried to get (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91332/7/0) notice the absolute paths in the 'fullpath' column. and compare with what you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
 with tree(id, Level, Hierarchy) as
(
 select id, 0, cast(Name as varchar(max))
   from filesystem
 union all
 select a.id, b.Level+1,
   b.Hierarchy+'/'+a.Name
  from filesystem a
  inner join tree b on a.parentid=b.id
)
select top(1) id, Hierarchy
 from tree
 where id=4
 order by Level desc
```

It will give you id with full file path.
TO read in details you can [check this](http://articles.opwernby.com/RQuery+Recursive+Queries+in+SQL+Server/p1.html)

Answer (score -1):

### Recursive CTE solution for SQL Server:

```
WITH FileSystem(id,name,parentID)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,'root',NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'folder',1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'subFolder',2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'subSubFolder',3
),
CTE_Recursion
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) filePath_id,ID,CAST(name AS VARCHAR(100)) name,parentID
    FROM FileSystem
    WHERE parentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT A.filePath_id,B.id,CAST(A.name + '\' +  B.name AS VARCHAR(100)),B.parentID
    FROM CTE_Recursion A
    INNER JOIN  FileSystem B
    ON A.ID = B.parentID
)

SELECT filePath_id,MAX(name) filePath
FROM CTE_Recursion
GROUP BY filepath_id
```

Results:

```
filePath_id          filePath
-------------------- -----------------------------------
1                    root\folder\subFolder\subSubFolder
```