# returning entries based on a is contained predicate with sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, predicate

I stumbled upon a very hideous problem, here is my table

```
filesystem (id, name, parentid);
```

and some entries for the example

```
(1, 'root', null)

(2, 'folder1', 1)
(3, 'subfolder1.1', 2)
(4, 'subfolder1.2', 2)

(5, 'folder2', 1)
(6, 'subfolder2.1', 5)
(7, 'subfolder2.2', 5)
(8, 'megaSubfolder', 6)
```

that leaves us with the following paths :

```
root
root/folder1
root/folder2
root/folder1/subfolder1.1
root/folder1/subfolder1.2
root/folder2/subfolder2.1
root/folder2/subfolder2.2
root/folder2/subfolder2.1/megaSubfolder
```

what i want is to select all the folders that is contained in another one

for example `megaSubfolder`, `subfolder2.1`, `subfolder2.2` are contained in `folder2` (id **5**)

How should I write the request as to return these 3 entries (id **8**, **7**, **6**) where the predicate is **5** for instance ?

Comment: A recursive cte will do this

Comment: This is the same as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136626/how-to-make-a-sql-loop just with a different start condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_path(id, name) AS (
        SELECT f.id, f.name
        FROM filesystem f
        WHERE id=5
      UNION ALL
        SELECT f.id, f.name
        FROM filesystem f
        JOIN search_path sf ON f.parentid=sf.id
)
SELECT * FROM search_path;
```

The top part of `UNION ALL` selects the starting rows of your query. The bottom part "connects" additional rows to the rows that have been selected previously.

The result includes the row with `id` of `5`. If you do not want it, add `WHERE id <> 5` after `SELECT * FROM search_path`.

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e85c0/4)

Comment: thanks that works nicely, is there a way to use it as a view ? and provide the id as a parameter in further requests of the view ? that would be interesting

Comment: @발렌텐 I don't think you can make a view out of this one, because the starting point would be different. You can build a view that supplies a transitive closure of your tree, but it would be large and hard to work with.